# How to track app by user id : Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am new to Google Analytics.
I want to track my application by unique user id.
I am using `Google Analytics SDK for Android v3`.
I have this code on `onStart()`.I read about user id and created a new view for user tracking.

```
Tracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker("UA-xxx-2");
tracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "Main Acitivty");
tracker.set("&uid", id);
tracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());
```

But I am not getting how can I get this uid in my Google Analytics Console,
I am trying to track user by their user_id , so I can get complete report of particular user.
I am able to get count of the total active user , screens and hit events.
But I didn't get any success on getting the same report user-wise.
I also tried to create custom dimension and metrics but those are also not reflecting on account.I have no idea Where can I check this field.

For custom variables :

```
  easyTracker.send(MapBuilder
         .createAppView()
         .set(Fields.customDimension(1), "premiumUser")
        .build()
         );
```

I have searched , but I didn’t find any good tutorial on this.

Any help, suggestion , reference link would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I am not very familiar with GA on Android apps.  However, on a website custom variables often can be used to differentiate users.

Comment: Thanks @MSchenkel ..do you have any example of creating custom variables. ?I tried but those are not reflecting on console .. or may be I am doing something wrong

Comment: Please contact directly and I can assist you.

Comment: Facing same issue.. did you get solution?@NibhaJain

Answer (score 4):

User Id is only used internally to make sure that the sessions from one user are tracked together - it just makes your stats more accurate, and enables cross device analytics.

You cannot acces the userId though:

[User ID - Feature Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/user-id)

> Limits
>
> The User ID value can not be queried as a dimension in reports in either the web interface or the APIs

Also be sure not to send any user id like name or email:

[User ID Policy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy)

> You will not upload any data that allows Google to personally identify an individual (such as certain names, social security numbers, email addresses, or any similar data)

Answer (score 1):

You can find User ID Converage under Behaviour in the Audience section

check this image:

[image]

Comment: Do you know what to do if User-ID Coverage is not present?  I've enabled user id tracking for the property (at least I followed the instructions to do so).